# Jquery prevent ONLY submit on enter

Tags: jquery, form-submit, keydown

Why this code works with the alert line commented, but dont work when not commented?

I want block the form submit, but allow other functions on enter (example, do $.get() in other page). Sorry for my bad english.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtPesquisaServidor').keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            //alert('enter!');
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I'm using Jquery 1.6.2.

EDIT: Done! The problem was the `alert`  https://jsfiddle.net/o0mkjnwk/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `.keydown()` method, try using `.on('keypress', function...`

See the following fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/p1agoka1/

EDIT: I see you're using jQuery 1.6.2. The .on() event handler requires at least 1.7.0. Is there any reason why you're using such an old version?

If you have some other older code that does not work with a newer version of jQuery, you could try to implement jQuery Migrate which re-enables some older features of jQuery not present in up-to-date versions. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Comment: is the first time working with jquery, but I will try to migrate to the latest plugin.

Comment: In that case, make sure to update it to something even more recent, such as 2.x, available here: https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: @feresjorge If this answer was helpful, please make sure to select it as the correct answer, and don't hesitate to ask if you need any more help :)