# event prevent default with enter key

Tags: jquery, events, form-submit

I am trying to prevent my `$('form')` from reloading when I press the enter key. This code is not working. Any suggestions?

```
$('form').on('keypress', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        form.reset();
    }
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery prevent ONLY submit on enter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789605/jquery-prevent-only-submit-on-enter)

Answer (score 0):

Return false `return false;` from your function if enter key is pressed, like:

```
$('form').on('keypress', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        form.reset();
        return false;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The code does not work because `form` in `form.reset()` is undefined.

Use

```
$(this)[0].reset()
```

---

```js
    $('form').on('keypress', function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this)[0].reset();
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="">
  <input type="text" id="textInput" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```